# problem with google speech to text model adaptation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

i have a problem with model adaptation in Cloud console.
when i use Phrase with custom class,i do something like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
i got this error,but i can't set or get customClassId in Cloud console,just customClassName,but is't wrong when i use it
[image]
in this code,request body has a customClassId.

how to set the customClassId in Cloud console?

Comment: Found this similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72393639/google-speech-to-text-cannot-use-custom-classes. Let me know if it helps or not.