# Google Speech-to-Text: Cannot use Custom Classes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I am following the [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1?&_ga=2.21261435.-1508770839.1617306393#phrase) to do Transcription jobs by providing it with a `PhraseSet` and `CustomClass`. From my understanding, the `PhraseSet` defines the kind of structures with the phrases that Google should expect. the `CustomClass` defines specific words in those phrases.

Example Phrase Set:

```
# Name: TextFriend
Items: [
 'Text my friend ${Name}', 'Write a message to ${Name}', 'Shoot a text to ${Name}'
]
```

Example Custom Class:

```
# Name: Name
Items: [
  'Kabena', 'Breagieszky', 'Sunni', 'Facebook', 'Bitbucket', 'GitHub'
]
```

When I try to create a transcription job, it fails with this error:

> Error running recognize request. Invalid recognition 'config': Undefined custom class references. referenced class ids: Archwires. defined class ids: .

I doubled checked things and it all seems to be set up correctly. I did it through the GCP Console. Here's all the relevant resources:

### Custom Class:
[image: Custom Class]

### Phrase Set:
[image: Phrase Set]

### Job Configuration:
[image: Job Configuration]

I appreciate any help or insight to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

For those of you who land here, I found the solution by digging deeper into the [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation-model#improve_transcription_results_using_a_customclass).

Instead of just using the `customClassId` in your phrase, you need to use the **full path**.

So:

```
// Don't do this:
Items: ['Shoot a text to ${Name}']

// Do this:
Items: ['Shoot a text to ${projects/0000/locations/global/customClasses/Name}']
```